# Composite links not properly built in text

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, hyperlinks

Maybe it's a known bug (I tagged it as a bug) or it is intentional.
I often find myself advicing less experienced user to read this page:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)

As you can see, the link is interrupted at the first occurrence of a comma.
It would be nice to see the link complete.

And, even worse, the link is truncated so that only this page is shown:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

and not the section to which I wanted the users to focus.

Comment: I should mention that this also breaks linking text ([like this](https://google.com)), so it's actually not possible to use that link unless you manually escape the url.

Comment: Exactly. You found better words than mine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is the space. It is unsafe to use space characters in URIs exactly because of this reason, it breaks on most text parsing systems.

Unless there is a special markup set, the parser does not know when the link stops. In order to avoid making everything after the text link a hyperlink, it stops at the first space.

It is always advised to encode unsafe characters. In this case space should become *%20*.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

**Workaround:**

The hyperlink button from the editor will do this automatically if you insert an URL with unsafe characters. Using the following link ....

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)

..will result in
a working and encoded hyperlink

> [enter link description here][1]
>
> [1]:
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

Modern browsers (or just Chrome?) tend to ignore this and display real spaces in the URI box. It is not safe however to use them everywhere.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you. It would be great if SO had the ability of replacing spaces with the `%20` sequence in links. In both answers and comments, too.

Comment: Firefox does that too, although copying out of the address bar will keep the encoded URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, we need some characters to mark the end of a URL and one such character is space. [Using spaces is unsafe in URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space) because this is such a common issue.

One way to go around it is encoding the spaces, and http has a special placeholder for space: "+"

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,+int,+int,+int)

which of course you can/should beautify with a proper link

> `[TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,+int,+int,+int))`

resulting in

> [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,+int,+int,+int))

Comment: It again brought me to [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)... :( The `%20` solution given by @Spokey works, though.

Comment: @DerGolem that's where it should take you, the second part after the `#` is an anchor within the page.

Comment: Which is where I want to go: to the anchor. Like [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))